# Add working directory to build

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7

I am having trouble adding dependancies that are located in my working directory, to my .jar. When I try to run the .jar from command line I get errors saying that files I am attempting to access do not exist. Why does netbeans not include the working directory in the build dependancies, seems like a pretty easy and obvious thing to do....

I am simply trying to read a file, located at res/settings/settings.txt. I have made my working directory the res folder so that in netbeans I access that file successfully through 'settings/settings.txt'. I attempted to make the settings folder a library so it would be added to the build, however it refused to copy it because it was a directory.

How can I add this file to the build so i can run it from command line?

Comment: This may depend on the on the type of project you created. For example, a Java Library will not include the project dependencies as part of its build process but a Java Application will. These are placed in the dist directory of your project. Under the project properties, you can specify the working directory that netbeans will use when it runs your project, but this has no bearing on the built project

Comment: Are you using an Ant based project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why should it?  The working directory is simply a "test" location for your application.  The build process is not a "packaging" process.

Netbeans provides you with a `build.xml` file which can you can modify to perform custom actions, but consider this, each time you build your application, these custom build actions/targets could be executed.  That could add considerable time to your build process.  If you're just making small changes, this might not be desirable.

Two solutions then come to mind.

1. You could create custom build targets within the `build.xml` file which you would need to trigger by right-clicking the `build.xml` file (in the files view) and selecting `Run Target` and choosing the required target from the cascading menu...from experience this is not as convenient as it sounds.  You could also run the `build.xml` file from the command line, specifying the targets you want...
2. Make another ant script which packaged your application separately.  This is similar to the first comment except that you completely divorce the build and package processes.

I work on a very large application, which was taking upwards of 15 mins to build (completely).  We wrote a utility which went through all the Netbeans project properties and built it's own dependency map, which then generated an Ant build script.  We then included this in our own packaging script, so we could build the application and package it within a single pass when we wanted to create a release.  This reduced the build down to something like 3 minutes (don't ask why, it just did), it also meant that we could remove the immediate dependency on Netbeans from our build process.

So.  The basic answer is.  Netbeans is a builder, not a packager.  In order to supply this support, you're going to have to write something yourself.  The easiest thing to do would be to simply write some Ant script to perform this aciton.  Where you do this is up to you.

Comment: I managed to get my files into my .jar. How do I reference these files from inside my code so the path is correct?

Comment: You need to use Class#getResource or Class# getReaourceAsInputStream to gain access to the resources. The path will be relative to the based on the class that is trying to load the resource